# Copy files in folders using ColdFusion (openBD Engine)

Tags: file-io, coldfusion, cfml, openbd

I have been asked to solve the following problem: copy files in batch of 3 in newly created folders. Example:  in folder let’s say “D:/TEST_CF/” there are 20 txt files. Divide them by 3 (the batch-give us 6 remainder 2), create 7 folders (in order to place the batches of 3 in the 6 folders and the remaining 2 files in the 7th folder). What I have done until now is to create the needed folders. But, I can’t copy the files into batches of 3 in the newly created folders. How should I tackle the above problem?

**The code block**

```
<html>
<body>

<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="UTF-8">

<cfset directory = "D:/TEST_CF/">
<cfdirectory directory="#directory#" name="files" action="list" type="file">
<cfset filecount = #files.RecordCount#>
<cfset divisor = 3>
<cfset division = #filecount# / #divisor#>
<cfset remainder = #filecount# MOD #divisor#>
<cfset folders_to_create = Ceiling(#division#)>

<cfoutput>

    <cfif directoryExists(directory)>
        <cfdirectory action="list" directory="#directory#" name="directories" recurse="true" type="dir" />
        <cfloop query="directories">
            <cfdirectory action="delete" directory="#directory#/#directories.name#" recurse="yes">
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>

    <cfloop from="1" to="#folders_to_create#" index="i">
        <cfdirectory
          action="create"
          directory="#directory#newfolder#i#">
    </cfloop>

    <cfif folders_to_create EQ 1>
        #folders_to_create#&nbsp;folder created
    <cfelse>
        #folders_to_create#&nbsp;folders created
    </cfif>

</cfoutput>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty - copying files or doing the threesies?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk The part that causing me problem is copy. I have changed the the above process using cfc. After folders creation all the files (20) are copied in the first folder. For the cfm follow [ http://pastebin.com/ugrjPJ7W ] and for the cfc follow [ http://pastebin.com/yXinvtvr ]

Comment: I dont have the exact syntac right now, but inside your folders to create loop, could you make a 2nd loop where you copy the files with filename file[1].filename, file[2].filename, etc...  I could post a sample code tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve said, you need a loop two or better a function to do the fileMove action.

**Note**

- The logic is just a POC. You can refine it to a better one.
- I have tried this code on CF10. It must work Okay on Open DB too.

  ```
  <cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="UTF-8">

  <cfscript>
      oDirectoryPath      = "D:/test_cf/"; //original Directory path
      files               = DirectoryList(oDirectoryPath, false, 'name', '*.*');
      filecount           = Arraylen(files);
      filePerFolder       = 3;
      numfoldersToCreate  = Ceiling(filecount/filePerFolder);

      function moveFilesToThisDirectory(dir,index){
          var beginAt = 1;
          var endAt   = begin + 2;
          var newDir  = ARGUMENTS.dir;

          beginAt = ARGUMENTS.index;

          if(beginAt neq 1){
              endAt = index * VARIABLES.filePerFolder;
              beginAt = endAt - (VARIABLES.filePerFolder - 1);
              if(endAt GT VARIABLES.fileCount){
                  endAt = VARIABLES.fileCount;
              }
          }

          while(beginAt LTE endAt){
              FileMove(oDirectoryPath & '\' & files[beginAt], newDir & '\' & files[beginAt]);
              beginAt = beginAt + 1;
          }

      }
  </cfscript>

  <cfif directoryExists(oDirectoryPath)>        
          <cfdirectory action="list" directory="#oDirectoryPath#" name="directories" recurse="true" type="dir" />
          <cfloop query="directories">
                  <cfdirectory action="delete" directory="#oDirectoryPath#/#directories.name#" recurse="yes">
          </cfloop>
  </cfif>

  <cfscript>

      i = 1;
      while(i LTE numfoldersToCreate){
          newDirectoryName = "#oDirectoryPath#newfolder#i#";
          DirectoryCreate(newDirectoryName);
          moveFilesToThisDirectory(dir:newDirectoryName,index:i );
          i = i + 1;
      }

      switch(numfoldersToCreate){
          case 0:
              WriteOutput(' No folder created');
              break;
          case 1:
              WriteOutput(' 1 folder created');
              break;
          default:
              WriteOutput(numfoldersToCreate & ' folders created');
      }
  </cfscript>
  ```

Comment: Many thanks for looking into my problem. I what to ask if I can find a good book in array manipulation techniques (or a tutorial)

Comment: Just a minor suggestion. You may want to use different variable names to avoid confusion, as `begin` and `end` typically have special meaning in most languages.

Comment: @Leigh good suggestion. I shall modify the code so that further search references will be neat.